# Before property unicode not working properly bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have searched for this question and visited https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/0ekoq but when I paste code in my project it's not loading Unicode

```css
section {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

section .section-title {
  color: #0d2d3e;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#what-we-do {
  background: #ffffff;
}

#what-we-do .card {
  padding: 1rem!important;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease;
  transition: .5s all ease;
}

#what-we-do .card:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
  box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
}

#what-we-do .card .card-block {
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#what-we-do .card .card-block a {
  color: #007b5e !important;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#what-we-do .card .card-block a i {
  display: none;
}

#what-we-do .card:hover .card-block a i {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#what-we-do .card .card-block:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 39px;
  color: #007b5e;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

#what-we-do .card .block-1:before {
  content: "\f0e7";
}

#what-we-do .card .block-2:before {
  content: "\f0eb";
}

#what-we-do .card .block-3:before {
  content: "\f00c";
}

#what-we-do .card .block-4:before {
  content: "\f209";
}

#what-we-do .card .block-5:before {
  content: "\f0a1";
}

#what-we-do .card .block-6:before {
  content: "\f218";
}

#what-we-do .card:hover .card-block:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease;
  transition: .5s all ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>CONSULTING</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="what-we-do">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h2 class="section-title mb-2 h1">OUR BEST SERVICES</h2>
      <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block block-1">
              <h3 class="card-title">Special title</h3>
              <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <a href="https://www.fiverr.com/share/qb8D02" title="Read more" class="read-more">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block block-2">
              <h3 class="card-title">Special title</h3>
              <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <a href="https://www.fiverr.com/share/qb8D02" title="Read more" class="read-more">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block block-3">
              <h3 class="card-title">Special title</h3>
              <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <a href="https://www.fiverr.com/share/qb8D02" title="Read more" class="read-more">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block block-4">
              <h3 class="card-title">Special title</h3>
              <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <a href="https://www.fiverr.com/share/qb8D02" title="Read more" class="read-more">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block block-5">
              <h3 class="card-title">Special title</h3>
              <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <a href="https://www.fiverr.com/share/qb8D02" title="Read more" class="read-more">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block block-6">
              <h3 class="card-title">Special title</h3>
              <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              <a href="https://www.fiverr.com/share/qb8D02" title="Read more" class="read-more">Read more<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

[Screenshot of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZzqA.png)

Whenever I came across before and after the property I faced issues like that can anyone solve my riddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can fix it by importing **Font Awesome** into the top of your CSS file and it will work.

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```